# Duda sobre la sintaxis de la inyeccion de dependencias

Tags: php

Partiendo, por ejemplo, desde esta clase

```
class Question 
{ 
    private $author; 
    private $question; 

    public function __construct($question, Author $author) 
    { 
        $this->author = $author; 
        $this->question = $question; 
    } 

    public function getAuthor() 
    { 
        return $this->author; 
    } 

    public function getQuestion() 
    { 
        return $this->question; 
    } 
}
```

En los parametros del constructor tenemos la clasica sintaxis(mi duda es sobre esa sintaxis) de la inyeccion de dependencias(Author $author), primero el namespace de la clase en cuestion y luego una variable, pero por mas que me he intentado documentar sobre el tema no encuentro una respuesta clara, no sé exactamente(me lo figuro pero no lo sé a ciencia cierta) a que equivale esta sintaxis.

Supongo que se le pasa la clase (Author) a la variable($author) para que esta variable tenga una instancia completa de la clase ¿Es asi?
Me gustaria que me ilustrarais con algún ejemplo, quizás sea una locura, ¿pero seria lo mismo(o equivaldria a ser algo parecido) hacer algo asi?

```
public function __construct($question, new Author $author) 
{ 
    $this->author = $author; 
    $this->question = $question; 
}
```

La pregunta general seria esa, al pasar el namespace como argumento y al lado la variable ¿Poseeria esa variable una instancia completa de la clase del namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que está haciendo con `public function __construct($question, Author $author)` es "TIPAR" el argumento, es decir, estás indicándole a la clase Question que solo puede aceptar como segundo argumento instancias de la clase Author.

La inyección de dependencias quiere decir que estás pasando la instancia necesaria para el funcionamiento de tu clase en lugar de instanciarla directamente en el método.

Normalmente, será un "container" el que instancie la dependencia y se la pase a la nueva clase.

El código `public function __construct($question, new Author $author)` no es válido y provocará un error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicacion, me queda un poco mas claro, ahora lo que no entiendo muy bien es donde ese container instanciará la dependencia pero bueno eso creo que lo preguntaré en otra pregunta.
Gracias de nuevo.